# Prototype - How to get child elements in prototype 1.6.0.3

Tags: get, hover, mouseover, prototypejs, children

I have a list with different products plus the details of them. The details are hidden by default. I'd like to know how i can show the details calling the childrens of the list elements on hover. Here's a link to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/CXrb2/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="cart-sidebar">
    <li>Product 1 <div class="product-details">Productinfo 1</div></li>
    <li>Product 2 <div class="product-details">Productinfo 2</div></li>
    <li>Product 3 <div class="product-details">Productinfo 3</div></li>
</div>
```

Prototype:

```
$$('.product-details').each(
    function (e) {
        e.hide();
    }
);
$$('#cart-sidebar li').invoke('observe', 'mouseover', function(e) {        
    // any help would be great :)   
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of many ways would be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CXrb2/6/):

```
$('cart-sidebar').select('li').each(function(el){
    $(el).observe('mouseover', function(){
        $(el).down('div').show();
    });
});
```